# Generating multi PDF (multi languages) from the same tex file

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I was wondering if there would be a feature that would allow me to write code

```
Je [te/vous] présente.
```

that would allow me to generate two versions:

```
Je te présente.
Je vous présente.
```

The idea is to have only one PDFLaTeX document and to generate a version in tutoiement and a version in vouvoiement.

Comment: Hello, you might have a better chance of getting an answer in a specific [Stack Exchange Channel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many packages which allow to produce multiple versions from the same source, e.g. the `beameraudience` package. However you could also create a simple switch yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifvous
%\voustrue %try with and without this line

\newcommand{\switch}[2]{%
  \ifvous%
    #1%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    
    Je \switch{vous}{te} présente.

\end{document}
```

If you would like to automatically produce two pdfs without commenting/uncommenting anything in the source, you could use the same techniques as shown in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583